# How to distinct zipcodes by state/region

Tags: zip-codes

Using the 2021 Zip Code Tabulation data, I want to create a web software that allows users to select certain zip codes mapped from Google Maps API. Problem is there are over 30k zip codes and retrieving all of those zip codes and their boundaries.
The solution is to let the user select which state/region to load, and only retrieve those zip codes.

How can I algorithmically assign a zip code to a specific region or state just using the zip code (60077, 12345, etc). Is there some pattern like 1000-3000 is west region, 3000-4000 is central region?

Comment: Zipcodes have a many-to-many relationship with both states and counties.

Comment: As https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/ and https://faq.usps.com/s/article/ZIP-Code-The-Basics note, there is some structure to zip codes. At one point, the first two digits of a zip code determined the state, not sure if that's true anymore.